# How can I store and retrieve files uploaded with fileInput after resetting it Shiny

Tags: r, file-io, shiny, upload, storage

I would like to create a storage to store and retrieve uploaded files even after fileInput is reset.

Basically every time user uploads a file with fileInput, in the future he is forced to click on doneUpload button which resets the fileInput text area and puts his file in the storage (no alternatives please).
At this point, user can go back and upload another file which will be put in the storage too.

From my point of view, I have all uploaded files which I can easily retrieve and manipulate. 
In other words, my question could be translated to: 
**how can I reset fileInput text area without resetting uploaded files?**

I have tried creating a reactive value to store uploaded files, however it does not work as I expected.

Here I show you an example to simplify my situation.

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(
  uiOutput("uploadFile"),
  actionButton("doneUpload","Done"),
  tableOutput("exampleTest"))


server<-function(input, output){

  output$uploadFile<-renderUI({
    fileInput("uploadFile", "Upload your file", accept = c(".csv"),placeholder="No files selected")
  })

observeEvent(input$doneUpload,{
    output$uploadFile<-renderUI({
      fileInput("uploadFile", "Upload your file", accept = c(".csv"),placeholder="No files selected")
    })
  })

  reactiveFileUploaded<-reactiveValues(fileUploaded=NULL)

  observe({
    req(input$uploadFile)
    reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded<-c(reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded,input$uploadFile$datapath)
  })

#Test to verify if the storage has been created. 
#Supposing two files have been uploaded, I retrieve the first one.
output$exampleTest<-renderTable({
    read.csv2(reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded[1])
  })

}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a much simpler approach for what you need - Just set `multiple = TRUE` in `fileInput()` so that it can accept multiple files at the same time. They can all be read and stored in a reactive in one go using `lapply`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("files", "Upload", multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("done", "Done Upload"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  all_data <- eventReactive(input$done, { # stores data in all files as a list of dataframes
    req(input$files)
    setNames(lapply(input$files$datapath, read.csv), sapply(input$files$name, basename))
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    # all_data()[[1]] # access first file; others can be accessed the same way
    lapply(all_data(), head) # shows first 6 rows of all files with their names
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ok, your solution is great. However, user is allowed to upload one file at a time and I just want to store uploaded files as I can retrieve and manipulate them, not read them. If you mange to find a solution it would be great! Thanks

Comment: @David I don't understand. There's no difference between uploading one at a time and uploading all at once. What do you mean by *manipulate them, not read them*? How do you manipulate without reading first? You can still manipulate any file by accessing it from `all_data()`.

Comment: Because in reality every file user uploads is associated with a text name. So user is allowed to upload only a single file and give it a name. Once it is done, he can go back and repeat the operation. You are right i gave a bad answer. I should be able to read the files first and then being able to manipulate them (or store them in a variable if you want).

Comment: Ok. Your reactive value all_data may be a good solution. However, I want to avoid uploading multiple files.

Comment: Would it be okay, if the dataframes (list elements in `all_data()`) are given same name as filename so that user doesn't have to give it a name manually? Basically just ask your users to name their file correctly which seems the same as naming them in the app.

Comment: Well, I create a text input area on purpose as user can give it a name manually. The given name has an impact on the project. If you find a solution, it would be great! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @David What you need can be done but it just seems unnecessarily complicated. Having code based on user input names is bound to fail as you have no control on what names they'll give. Try my updated answer and if you are still not convinced I'll update to what you are asking for.

Comment: I added some constraints on the text input area, however at the end I follow your advice on the potential vulnerability of my project. So I removed the text input area and the associated name to the uploaded file becomes the csv file name itself. However I am still stick to the single file upload. In the future I will see whether a multiple upload may be convenient. In this case I would still use the csv file names rather than the text input area. Anyway, why do you strongly recommend me to avoid user input names? Why may be bad having no control over the names users give? Thanks

Comment: @David It should be okay if you are only using user input names for display purposes. If it affects actual code then *"I added some constraints on the text input area"* gets pretty messy over time and just not worth it. You wouldn't let users name tables define schema in a database, would you? I think the same principal applies. Finally if you are going by my method then I don't see any advantage of doing one file at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Quite Simple, just read the file before clearing the input, after the User has confirmed the Input.

Currently you are reading (and saving) the file the moment the User has selected it, no matter if he wants to upload it or not. Also it seems like you are somehow triggering a loop after selecting a file constantly adding the file to the reactive value.

Also with the datapath you are saving only the filepath not the filecontent, and the filepath also directs to the temp folder so I would recommend changing that routine as well.

But for the most basic functionalities you described the following code should get the job done. (I also added a simple check for content in the filesUploaded variable, so that the error message doesn't appear on start up)

library(shiny)

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  uiOutput("uploadFile"),
  actionButton("doneUpload","Done"),
  tableOutput("exampleTest"))


server<-function(input, output){

  output$uploadFile<-renderUI({
    fileInput("uploadFile", "Upload your file", accept = c(".csv"),placeholder="No files selected")
  })

  reactiveFileUploaded<-reactiveValues(fileUploaded=c())


  observeEvent(input$doneUpload,{
    req(input$uploadFile)
    reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded<-c(reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded ,input$uploadFile$datapath)


    output$uploadFile<-renderUI({
      fileInput("uploadFile", "Upload your file", accept = c(".csv"),placeholder="No files selected")
    })
  })



  #Test to verify if the storage has been created. 
  #Supposing two files have been uploaded, I retrieve the first one.
  output$exampleTest<-renderTable({
    if(length(reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded)>1)
    read.csv2(reactiveFileUploaded$fileUploaded[1])
  })

}



shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: I have just tried your code. It looks great and your arguments are correct. However, I get no table after I upload two files. If everything works as it should, I would get the first uploaded csv file.